# always stay on number of page (e.g page 3) pagination, if REFRESH page on JQUERY w/o ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```js
var pager = new Imtech.Pager();
$(document).ready(function() {
    pager.paragraphsPerPage = 5; // set amount elements per page
    pager.pagingContainer = $('#content'); // set of main container
    pager.paragraphs = $('div.z', pager.pagingContainer); // set of required containers
    pager.showPage(1);
});
```

```css
body {background:#eee;font-family:Verdana, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;margin:0;padding:0}

.example {background:#FFF;width:1000px;font-size:80%;border:1px #000 solid;margin:0.5em 10% 0.5em;padding:1em 2em 2em;-moz-border-radius:3px;-webkit-border-radius:3px}

#content p {text-indent:20px;text-align:justify;}

#pagingControls ul {display:inline;padding-left:0.5em}

#pagingControls li {display:inline;padding:0 0.5em}
```

```html
<script src="https://planetwedding.net/latihan/suport_js.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="example">
    <h3><a href="#">Paragraph pagination sample</a></h3>

    <div id="content">
        <div class="z">Sergey LUKYANENKO - The Boy and the Darkness - Chapter 1. The Sun Kitten.</div>
        <div class="z">Everything happened because I got ill.</div>
        <div class="z">It was already two in the afternoon, and I was lying in bed flicking through "Peter Pan" - I must have read it a hundred times over. I had long since pulled off the bandage my mother had tied around my neck in the morning, and thrown it into a corner. I simply can't understand - how can cotton wool soaked in vodka possibly help a cough? I don't argue with my mum, of course, but after she leaves I look after myself in my own way - namely, lie in bed with a book and wait for my germs to get tired of such a boring method of passing time. It usually helps - perhaps not at once, but after a day or three. A good thing, really, that the street outside looked quite miserable - the sun poking out for brief moments, only to make room for a patchy, nasty drizzle. Though, the sun never actually peeked into the room - our house is so unfortunately placed that it is in the shadows of the new nine-floor high-rises on every side. "The only use for such a flat is to grow mushrooms", - dad used to say, back when he still lived with us.</div>
        <div class="z">I put my book down on the floor next to the bed, and lay on my back. Perhaps, had I shut my eyes now, nothing would have happened. But there I was, lying staring at the ceiling and listening to the ticking of the clock in the hallway.</div>
        <div class="z">And a speck of sunlight jumped into the room through the glass. Small - the size of my hand - but surprisingly bright. As though the window was open, with bright summer sun outside. Someone was probably playing with a mirror on the balcony of the house across the street.</div>
        <div class="z">The rabbit floated across the ceiling, climbed down a wall, made a vase on the dressing-table glint, and stopped, shaking slightly, on my headrest.</div>
        <div class="z">- Don't go, - I said for some reason, knowing that in a moment the mirror would shift and the rabbit would leave my room forever. - Stay...</div>
        <div class="z">And that's when it all started.</div>
        <div class="z">The sun rabbit tore free of the bed and floated in the air. I didn't even realise at first that such things don't happen. It was only when the flat spot hanging in the air started puffing out to form a fuzzy orange ball that I understood - a miracle had happened.</div>
        <div class="z">I closed my eyes for a second, but when I opened them again, the kitten hadn't disappeared. In fact, he'd flown closer.</div>
        <div class="z">- I don't believe in fairy tales, - I told myself. - I'm grown up now.</div>
        <div class="z">- A sun rabbit, - replied the kitten, examining himself curiously. - What an appearance.. do I look like one?</div>
        <div class="z">- <b>Like</b> what?</div>
        <div class="z">- Like a <p style="font-weight:bold;color:red;">sun</p> rabbit.</div>
        <div class="z">- More like a kitten.</div>
        <div class="z">- Hardly better, - stated the Kitten sadly and stretched out. And I didn't think of anything better than repeating:</div>
        <div class="z">- Who're you?</div>
        <div class="z">- So you mean - any rabbit can come to life if one just calls it? - I asked cautiously. For some reason it seemed to me the Kitten would be hurt at the question again. But he just shook his head proudly:</div>
        <div class="z">- As if! Any! Only True Light, reflected in a True Mirror, can come to life.</div>
    </div>

    <div id="pagingControls"></div>
</div>
```

Why if i get page of pagination always stay on page (e.g page 3), if user REFRESH the website ??

Because, my page pagination if REFRESH always back to default page (page 1).

Thank before it!

Comment: After refresh jquery dosen't know about previous values. so try to use localStorage and after page refresh use this localtorage value for the pagination .like `pager.showPage(localstorage value);`

Comment: Why the need of using caps like this, it will not get you any better results

Comment: Why is this tagged with PHP?